# The font for constructible universe L

Tags: fonts, mathjax

How do I type L, HOD and V as in the snippet below :

[image]

Comment: `\mathsf{L}` and `\mathsf{V}`, perhaps?

Comment: Sould be `\mathsf{L}`, &c.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to define a command like `\wordvar{#1}` that allows you to define `\HOD` as `\wordvar{HOD}`.

This definition should work:

```
 \newcommand\wordvar[1]{\textnormal{\sffamily\bfseries\upshape\selectfont #1}}
```

This gets you the spacing and ligatures of a word, rather than the product of math variables H, O and D.  Note that, if you write the product `\V \HOD \L`, it would run together as VHODL, so either write `\V \cdot \HOD \cdot \L`, or use `\mathop{\wordvar{HOD}}` in the middle to get spacing like 2 sin t or a log b.

You could also use the `\mathbfsfup` alphabet of `unicode-math` or the `\mathsfbf` alphabet of `isomath`.

Answer (score 1):

Just I add a MWE after the correct comments.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
We always have $\boldsymbol{\mathsf{L}}\subseteq \boldsymbol{\mathsf{HOD}} \subseteq \boldsymbol{\mathsf{V}}$ (\verb|bold-mode|)\par
We always have $\mathsf{L}\subseteq \mathsf{HOD} \subseteq \mathsf{V}$ (\verb|normal-mode|)\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that `\boldsymbol{\mathsf{#1}}`, from `amsmath`, is compatible with more packages than just `bm`, including `unicode-math`.

Comment: @Davislor Approved....and it is correct. :-)